# Convert HTTPResponse Message (Json)

Tags: c#, json, .net, list, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to convert the content of a response message to a list of items contained within the response message and keep running into issues, the returned json looks like this:
[Jason output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE2Sz.png)

Here is the whole returned response content:

```json
{
    "Version": 1,
    "Result": "Success",
    "Data": {
        "Tasks": [
            {
                "Oid": "f70b1a46-690f-4637-886b-f90f035a11e8",
                "CreatedOn": "2022-07-15T00:07:41.553Z",
                "ChangedOn": "2022-07-15T03:39:58.373Z",
                "Subject": "233817 3693 Range Rd",
                "Description": "",
                "Comment": "",
                "IsStarted": true,
                "IsFinished": true,
                "IsFinalAppointment": false,
                "ScheduledOn": "2022-07-15T09:37:41.553",
                "ProductionDeadline": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                "ScheduledStart": "2022-07-15T09:45:00",
                "ScheduledEnd": "2022-07-15T09:50:00",
                "RealStart": "2022-07-15T09:45:00",
                "RealEnd": "2022-07-15T09:50:00",
                "CalculatedSeconds": 300.0000,
                "IdleSeconds": 0,
                "ScheduledDuration": "PT5M",
                "RealDuration": "PT5M",
                "Status": 2,
                "PercentComplete": 100,
                "HasFinishedItems": true,
                "IsCustomTask": false,
                "AppointmentType": "OrderSpecificAppointment",
                "OrderItemCount": 31,
                "OrderItemPartsCount": 56,
                "MaterialUsageTotal": 58.3280000000,
                "MaterialUsageTotalConverted": 58.328,
                "MaterialUsageNet": 46.9659000000,
                "MaterialUsageNetConverted": 46.9659,
                "MaterialUsageScrap": 11.3621000000,
                "MaterialUsageScrapConverted": 11.3621,
                "MaterialUsageTotalWeight": 263.4676,
                "MaterialUsageTotalWeightConverted": 263.4676,
                "MaterialUsageNetWeight": 212.1449000000,
                "MaterialUsageNetWeightConverted": 212.14490,
                "MaterialUsageScrapWeight": 51.3227000000,
                "MaterialUsageScrapWeightConverted": 51.32270,
                "Station": {
                    "_Value": "Centurio",
                    "oid": "f7f3c5fe-49f0-4a9a-b366-29c4ab990fc7"
                },
                "Materials": [
                    {
                        "_Value": "STEALTH MATTE .55 (MONUMENT†)",
                        "oid": "4889a4f2-75c6-4fb2-b57d-d393ff495ef1",
                        "externalID": "161539"
                    }
                ],
                "MaterialCoils": [],
                "MaterialDimensions": [],
                "PreviousDependencies": [],
                "NextDependencies": [
                    {
                        "_Value": "",
                        "oid": "4699df81-4d5c-456c-904d-389a08f60a82",
                        "start": "2022-07-17T03:37:00",
                        "station": "Unallocated Folding Station"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Oid": "4699df81-4d5c-456c-904d-389a08f60a82",
                "CreatedOn": "2022-07-15T00:07:41.567Z",
                "ChangedOn": "2022-07-15T08:27:19.297Z",
                "Subject": "233817 3693 Range Rd",
                "Description": "",
                "Comment": "",
                "IsStarted": true,
                "IsFinished": true,
                "IsFinalAppointment": true,
                "ScheduledOn": "2022-07-15T09:37:41.567",
                "ProductionDeadline": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                "ScheduledStart": "2022-07-17T03:37:00",
                "ScheduledEnd": "2022-07-17T06:33:00",
                "RealStart": "2022-07-17T03:37:00",
                "RealEnd": "2022-07-17T06:33:00",
                "CalculatedSeconds": 10560.0000,
                "IdleSeconds": 0,
                "ScheduledDuration": "PT2H56M",
                "RealDuration": "PT2H56M",
                "Status": 2,
                "PercentComplete": 100,
                "HasFinishedItems": true,
                "IsCustomTask": false,
                "AppointmentType": "OrderSpecificAppointment",
                "OrderItemCount": 31,
                "OrderItemPartsCount": 56,
                "MaterialUsageTotal": 46.9659000000,
                "MaterialUsageTotalConverted": 46.9659,
                "MaterialUsageNet": 46.9659000000,
                "MaterialUsageNetConverted": 46.9659,
                "MaterialUsageScrap": 0.0000000000,
                "MaterialUsageScrapConverted": 0.0,
                "MaterialUsageTotalWeight": 212.1449,
                "MaterialUsageTotalWeightConverted": 212.1449,
                "MaterialUsageNetWeight": 212.1449000000,
                "MaterialUsageNetWeightConverted": 212.14490,
                "MaterialUsageScrapWeight": 0.0000000000,
                "MaterialUsageScrapWeightConverted": 0.00000,
                "Station": {
                    "_Value": "Unallocated Folding Station",
                    "oid": "7ce5334a-b05c-4511-be7b-1a83d2bf8d4c"
                },
                "Materials": [
                    {
                        "_Value": "STEALTH MATTE .55 (MONUMENT†)",
                        "oid": "4889a4f2-75c6-4fb2-b57d-d393ff495ef1",
                        "externalID": "161539"
                    }
                ],
                "PreviousDependencies": [
                    {
                        "_Value": "",
                        "oid": "f70b1a46-690f-4637-886b-f90f035a11e8",
                        "start": "2022-07-15T09:45:00",
                        "station": "Centurio"
                    }
                ],
                "NextDependencies": []
            }
        ]
    },
    "Details": ""
}
```

I wish to extract each task from the "Tasks" element into a list (I have created a class to hold each Task element). So far my code looks like this:

```
public async void AppointmentsAsync(int taskScheduleID)
{
   HttpResponseMessage taskList;
   using (RevSchedDataContext context = new RevSchedDataContext())
   {
        string TimePrint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimePrint"];
        schedule = (from s in context.TaskSchedules.Where(x => x.TaskScheduleID == taskScheduleID) select s).FirstOrDefault(); 
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://bendex.revroof.com.au/microsea/BendexRevBend/import/1.0/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
        taskList = await client.GetAsync($"{client.BaseAddress}GetOrderScheduledTasksListJson?did=233817");
        var products = await taskList.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var mtLists = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BendexTaskList>(products);                
    }
 }
```

When putting a breakpoint on mtLists line and stepping mtLists never get populated.

Regards
Peter

Answer (score -2):

I have found a solution to my problem thanks to the following site: https://json2csharp.com/
This enabled me to create the correct required classes to deserialize the json output in the format required to process.
New calling code:

```
       Root scheduledTaskList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(products);

            foreach(var tsk in scheduledTaskList.Data.Tasks)
            {
               //ToDo: pull required data and update table


            }
```

Regards
Peter